# Unable to connect MongoDb on Windows

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

I have installed mongodb.msi(installed in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin) and C:\data\db is created. But whenever I try to connect to mongodb it results in connection fail. From command promt, first I run mongod.exe and then mongo.exe and it results in this error:
[image]

Comment: And probably being what it sounds like. Do you still have the other command prompt open with the running `mongod` in it? Or are you trying to run both things in the same command prompt window?

Comment: From same command promt window

Comment: Well there is your problem as you have shut down the server. You need to leave it running so that there is something to connect to. Just use two command prompt windows. Or follow the [installation instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) and start `mongod` as a service.

Comment: Still the problem is not fixed.I run mongod.exe and mongo.exe from 2 command promts still results same error

Comment: Again you say you "run it", but is it still running? This is not hard, and there are tutorials everywhere. This really is not the place to be asking when there are step by step guides everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

/bin directory need to be added in system variable PATH